# Cross encryption between Sql Server and Teradata

Tags: sql-server, encryption, teradata

I need to store encrypted data on MS SQLServer and read them on Teradata.
These datas must be:

1. Writed to MSSQL database, crypted;
2. Copied from MSSQL to Teradata, still encrypted;
3. Red and decrypted by Teradata.

Is there a shared encryption method between both DBMS?

Comment: Why not just use the same encryption algorithm with the same keys?

Comment: This is where a solution similar to what is offered by Protegrity (there are other companies out there too) may come in to play and provide an enterprise solution for encryption and tokenization of data in your enterprise.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it might be worth the try to see if MS-based encryption will work on a linked Teradata server. So all the encryption & decryption is performed by the SS engine on both backends.

Comment: @Shahar , I don't know how to choose the encryption algorithm on MS nor no Teradata. Can you help?

Comment: @RobPaller **Protegrity** can be a solution but double license (MS+TD) it's probably too expensive. I can't find any other compertitor, do you know someone? Or is it possible to implement my own algorithm via assembly?

Comment: @access_granted, **encrypt and decrypt via MS** could have been a solution if the enviroments could talk, but they are completely separated. I have to rely on Teradata on one side, and MS SQL or MS SSIS on the other.